# BotKit Slack Bot to Microsoft Teams Bot

Tags: botframework, slack, botkit, microsoft-teams

I recently built a slack bot via the BotKit toolkit and now want to be able to expand from just slack to many other services. Basically, I was reading https://venturebeat.com/2016/11/02/how-bots-will-work-on-microsoft-teams/
and it states that

> "The integration means Microsoft Bot Framework users will be able to make bots for Slack, and Botkit users will be able to bring their bots to additional platforms, like Telegram, Kik, Twilio, and Skype. (Before the change, Botkit was only able to make bots for Slack and Facebook Messenger.)"

However, it is not clear to me how this can be accomplished. Do you mind explaining this to me or pointing me in the right direction? From what I understand, it should be a simple process of having my slackbot basically run within Microsoft Teams or Skype or whatever service.

Thanks!

Comment: I can't tell if you know this from your question, but BotKit and Bot Framework are 2 different things.  In the bot framework if you want to expand to more channels there is a setup similar to what you did for slack on each channel.  Are you looking to build a new bot on Bot Framework?  or just expand yours on BotKit?

Answer (score 2):

The [VentureBeat](https://venturebeat.com/2016/11/02/how-bots-will-work-on-microsoft-teams/) link for the Public Preview of Microsoft Teams was referring to the ability to use bots written for Slack (via BotKit or otherwise) within Microsoft Teams with little or no modification necessary. This capability is provided by [Message.io](http://message.io/home). You can contact them for more information or look on their website.

Microsoft Teams also has a native bot platform - the [Microsoft Bot Framework](https://dev.botframework.com/) (which also supports Slack, Skype, Facebook, and several other chat platforms). BotKit does not yet support Bot Framework.

(@JasonSowers)[https://stackoverflow.com/users/3011564/jasonsowers] is correct - BotKit and Bot Framework are two different bot platforms; today Microsoft teams supports one via Message.io and one natively.

Answer (score 0):

So I think your path is:

1. Register your bot in the [Bot Framework](https://github.com/howdyai/botkit/blob/master/docs/readme-botframework.md) to host the bot, referencing the Botkit. Make sure you add Microsoft Teams as a channel.
2. Create a package for your bot and [Sideload it][3] in Teams to test.